# The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher. showing when debugging on Android studio

Tags: flutter, kotlin, gradle

when try to building my flutter some of errors showing

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
project ':flutter_native_timezone' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s

Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

build.gradle file (changed kotlin version)

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.21'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

kotlin plugin is up to date on android studio
Also tried to debug with latest version but no use

I searched another articles but not solved my problem.

Tanks for your helping advance

Comment: Can you show your **android -> gradle -> wrapper -> gradle-wrapper.properties** file code and also try changing to **ext.kotlin_version=1.7.10**

Comment: distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip

Comment: flutter_native_timezone package is configured with kotlin 1.3.50 and based on your config your project supports only higher than kotlin 1.5.20.. there is two options if you want to use that package with your project
First, configure your project with kotlin 1.3.50 and also reduce gradle version. Second, fork the package repo in github then configure it with latest kotlin and gradle version as your project then use that repo in pubspec.yaml

Comment: ext.kotlin_version=1.7.10 changed when same error showing

Comment: **[flutter_timezone](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_timezone)** or you can use this plugin instead of **flutter_native_timezone**. Its a fork with updated kotlin version.

Comment: which version is better to use